# How to use perform(aSelector: , with: , afterDelay: , inModes: ) to pause a CABasicAnimation after a delay

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-animations

I am using `perform(aSelector: , with: , afterDelay: , inModes: )` to pause an animation after a specified delay. However, I keep getting an Unrecognized Selector Error. I am not sure what could possibly be causing this.

Sample Code (Updated):

```
    class ExpandingSelectedLayer: CALayer, CAAnimationDelegate
    {

    let expandingAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.bounds))
expandingAnim.perform(#selector(expandingAnim.pauseAnim), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0, inModes: [RunLoopMode.commonModes])
    }


    extension CABasicAnimation 
    {
            @objc func pauseAnim()
            {
                print("called pause Anim")
                self.speed = 0

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the `anArgument` argument in [`perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform) is the argument to pass to the method. The selector in your question doesn't take any arguments but your `perform` call is passing it an argument. Since `pauseAnim` doesn't take any arguments you would just pass `nil` for the `anArgument` argument.

Second: It's not clear from your question where the `pauseAnim` method is defined. Unless it's a method on `CABasicAnimation` (or somewhere in its class hierarchy) you won't be able to call that method on an instance of `CABasicAnimation`. If this method is defined on a view controller or other object you would use that as the receiver instead (possibly `self`).